# is StreamBulider will consider data as new reads for twice reads and change data or only for changing ones

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

i know that `.get()`will consider any data from it's collection as new reads but what about the following code

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(        
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.userId)
                                    .collection("allEvents").snapshots(),
```

Calling `.snapshot()` fetches the data, then will listen to changes. Now it will consider fetch data  and changes ones as reads OR only will consider changes ones as reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are listening for changes in real-time changes, it means that the first time you attach the listener, you get all documents that correspond to the query. Meaning that you have to pay a number of reads that is equal to the number of documents that the query returns. Right after that, every time a property within a document changes, you are notified according to that change. This means that you'll only be charged with that particular operation and nothing more.

Comment: does it mean it will reads all data as new reads  every time i turn the listen on? for example if want to listen to collections docs then i disposed the listen then i listen again in 10 secs after .. it will reads all docs as new again ?

Comment: No, you'll be charged again only if it takes more than 30 minutes. Check this article, [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e).

Comment: thanks but the previous code in my question it was StreamBuilder.snapshots() Widge .. does it itself listen ?

Comment: Yes, but you should also call listen, as Peter explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40).